# how to display an image from scroll view and how to add an infinite scroll?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a scroll view with two images and I want the user when they select an image to display it in the main image view, above the scroll view as I have it in my xml. Also I would to know how to implement infinite scrolling in the horizontal scroll view.

```xml
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="166dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="125dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="125dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/seal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="166dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image_radius"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/badge1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/seal_border_4021100" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/badge2"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/image_radius"
                android:src="@drawable/otehr_seal" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself by searching...

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.badge1:
            badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.badge1);
            tophone = R.drawable.badge1;
            break;
        case R.id.badge2:
            badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.badge2);
            tophone = R.drawable.badge2;
            break;
        case R.id.badge3:
            badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.badge3);
            tophone = R.drawable.badge3;
            break;
        case R.id.badge4:
            badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.badge4);
            tophone = R.drawable.badge4;
            break;
        case R.id.badge5:
            badge.setImageResource(R.drawable.badge5);
            tophone = R.drawable.badge5;
            break;
        case R.id.badgebtn:
            InputStream yea = getResources().openRawResource(tophone);
            Bitmap whatever = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(yea);

            try {
                getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(whatever);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();


            }
            break;

        default:
    }
```